# Linux fullscreening video

Tags: linux, x11, video

So I can only fullscreen some certain sites' videos. Youtube works sometimes as does another (entertainment) site.

Both are using Flash, I do not have YT set to use HTML5.

Clicking fullscreen freezes the video but it does not show as fullscreen. Audio continues working. I can hit Esc to close out of the non-functioning "fullscreen" video, but then the smaller embedded one does not start. I will have to refresh the page.

What can I do to make this work on everything?

Comment: Can you give some details about what is working and what not? Like which command should do what, but does not?

Comment: Added some more info